# Set custom cookie to ffmpeg http request

Tags: android, cookies, ffmpeg, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I use [ijkplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer)  at my project to show a video stream (it based on ffmpeg lib), but I had change request and now I have to send some data in cookie for each request to the server. So I figured out that there's http.c file which works with each request and added test cookie to cookie field

```
char data[] = {'t','e','s','t','=','r','2','d','2',';','p','a','t','h','=','/',';'};
s->cookies = data;
```

I looked into wireshark, and I saw that my requests was sent with this cookie, but after first sending I receive this signal:

```
libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa0c013e8 in tid 27629 (ff_read)
```

Maybe somebody had same problem and can help me

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found solution. Problem was that my cookie char array wasn't in heap. So I did malloc needed byte to cookies and do strcpy to this array